# How to add Row Number Column at the beginning of my table in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, row-number

```
select 
    CodeColumn, NameColumn, UnitCostColumn, DiscountRateColumn,
    TotalColumn, DescriptionColumn,
    row_number() over (order by CodeColumn) AS RowNumber
from 
    GoodsTable1
```

This is the code I use. But it adds `RowNumber` at the end of my table. I don't want that

Comment: Your code adds the row number to the *result set* but not to the *table*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move that "column" to the beginning of the select list:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CodeColumn) AS RowNumber, -- Here!
       CodeColumn,
       NameColumn,
       UnitCostColumn,
       DiscountRateColumn,
       TotalColumn,
       DescriptionColumn
FROM   GoodsTable1
```

Comment: thank you. I appreciate your answer. does this way of adding row number have any weaknesses? cause I searched in web many people had very larger codes for adding row number! :(